# JavaScript best practice naming convention for DOM element

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a **best practice**, or **industry-wide standard** for JavaScript naming convention for **DOM element**?

Take the following example:

```
var tarzan = document.getElementById('foobar');
```

What would be the most acceptable name to use so that a **DOM element** could be **differentiated** from another type of var? Should it be...

1. DOM_tarzan
2. DOMtarzan
3. elementTarzan
   .... so on and so forth?

I want to be able to tell the difference by just looking at the variable. For example, if I see:

```
DOM_tarzan.remove();
```

... I know straightaway that "DOM_tarzan" is a DOM element, and that it is employing the standard JavaScript remove() method.

There is no mistaking or guesswork that "DOM_tarzan" is a custom object that has a user-defined "remove()" method.

Thanks.

Comment: You're basically describing [hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation)

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you can simply add a dollar in front of the variable name: $variable

Comment: @MackieeE, DOM_tarzan.remove(); works too.

Comment: A DOM object could be lots of things - an element, collection, document. They all have different interfaces, so DOM is likely too general. There are DOM objects that don't have a remove method.

Comment: @RobG, I'm referring to the naming convention for DOM element.

Comment: @HoneyBadger—then probably "Element_tarzan" would be better.

Answer (score 9):

For indicating that a JS object variable references a DOM element object, I append `El` (or `Elem`) as a suffix to the variable name, as in

```
var tarzanElem = document.getElementById('foobar');
```

Comment: this is very clear and also works if you are writing angular directives (where you probably don't want to use the '$' prefix

Comment: @PeterHollingsworth the $ prefix is generally only applied to elements that have been selected by jquery and have jquery methods available

Answer (score 2):

Whether I include jQuery in my projects or not, i like my naming convention of variables to be  `$variable`. Then I can easily see if the variable is a DOM element.

Comment: Is this a standard, best-practice? Or is it personal preference? I would like to know what is the best practice for naming a DOM element. For example, Could I do DOM_tarzan = $('#foobar') and then use DOM_tarzan throughout my code instead of having to continually type $('#foobar')?

Comment: It is a personal preference. Yes, you can do it like that if you want :) (Btw; If jQuery is included in the project its a common practice to use the `$`sign. It tells that the variable contains a jQuery object.

Comment: Well, but if you're using  then jQuery, it's perhaps better to follow the convention, $tarzan = $('#foobar'). Funny sidenote: DOM-tarzan in dutch is something like dumb-tarzan.